# Kendo Export as PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, kendo-ui

I am calling kendo.drawing.drawDOM method in #PrintPDF button click. When the button is clicked it goes to on success of the button click, there i am getting the partial view result.  Now i want to pass this partial view result to be created as a pdf document. I am not sure how to pass the partial view result as input elements of kendo.drawing.drawDOM.

Note : $.parseHTML(result) does not work.

```
$("#PrintPDF").click(function () {         

        var url = "_PrintPDFPartialView";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: $("#StId").val()
            },   
     success: function (result) 
           {
             kendo.drawing.drawDOM($.parseHTML(result))
             .then(function (group) {
                 // Render the result as a PDF file
                 return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group, {
                     paperSize: "auto",
                     multiPage: true,   
                     });
                 }).done(function (data) {    },
                    )};
           });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [source](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pdf-export/page-layout)

```
$("#PrintPDF").click(function () {         
    var url = "_PrintPDFPartialView";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: $("#StId").val()
        },   
 success: function (result) 
       {
             var $result = $(result);

         kendo.drawing.drawDOM($result)
         .then(function (group) {
             // Render the result as a PDF file
              kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "test.pdf");
             }).done(function (data) {    },
                )};
       });
```

Comment: parameter for Kendo drawing.drawDOM (elements) should be a element. If i assign this result to a        <div id="pdfresult"></div> then if i pass it to kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#pdfResult").html(result)) then it works. But this <div> will be visible in the page. I dont want this div to be visible . It should be a just content holder for the pdf. I am not going to show it in Webpage.